# Is the $HOME environment variable always set on a Linux system?

Tags: environment-variables, home

Assuming the machine is running a Linux kernel, sessions make use of the Bash shell and everything is using default configurations (no user has made any changes to config files), can we assume that the `$HOME` environment variable is always set?

Comment: `nobody` doesn't have a home!  (It's `nobody`, the user.)

Comment: @devnull not having a home (ie. having a home directory specified that doesn't exist), doesn't mean the $HOME env. variable cannot be set. If it is set, it just doesn't have to point to an existing directory nor to the home entry in `/etc/passwd`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes. The [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) *requires* the OS to set a value for $HOME:

> HOME
>       The system shall initialize this variable at the 
>       time of login to be a pathname of the user's home
>       directory. See pwd.h.

What about user `nobody`?

```
# su - nobody
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
$ echo $HOME
/
```

Even though `nobody` has no true home, `HOME` is set to the root directory.

Comment: It isn't the shell that sets `HOME` — none of the common shells does except zsh. It's the program that logs you in (including methods like cron).